# Safe to run LED strip extension wire under an oven?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance, safety, low-voltage

I'm installing LED strip lights around the base of our kitchen cabinets, but there's an oven right in the middle of it. Is it safe to run extension wire ([like this](https://www.superlightingled.com/6pin-2022awg-power-wire-extension-cable-328ft1m-for-rgbcct-led-strip-lights-p-1967.html)) under the oven?

If it matters, the flooring under the oven is slate tile.

Comment: Imagine it is not in the top ten recommended places.  Just found out a few years ago that the storage draw under ovens is not to store pots and pans.  It is to keep food/plates warm when cooking.

Comment: If you put it in plastic or even metal conduit for protection.

Answer (score 1):

Run it around the back of the oven just above floor level.  Attach it to the cabinet walls and the back wall, just the same way you're attaching the strips to the baseboard.

That way the wire won't be damaged by the oven's feet when you pull the oven out for cleaning or repairs.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is class II wiring it should not be very difficult. It mainly depends on how hot it will get and the chance for physical damage. Assuming the oven is properly insulated it should not be a problem. My major concern would be if you need to remove the oven does it slide on the floor and clear the wire. If not you may have to make it removable. If you have access going down under and up would be very easy. This would work if the slate does not go under the cabinets.